# How to modify the baseline hazard in Weibull regression according in r?

Tags: r, regression, simulation, survival-analysis, weibull

How can I specify **baseline hazard function in r for Weibull regression*** according to my preference, i.e in my research problem my time scale is age and the follow-up starts from age 30 and ends at the age when we have an outcome event or right censoring? How can I incorporate this information in the baseline of the Weibull regression?

Let me know if there is any need for clarification

Comment: Have a look at the package **flexsurv**.

Comment: Could you also help me with this -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579684/simulation-of-an-time-to-event-covariate

Comment: Woudn't you just calculate a time variable (for entry into the `Surv` call) to be `age at death` or `age at censoring`minus 30?